# Setting returned api data as react state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Im trying to set the state of this react component below. the variable rankAndTeam contains the "prints=>" data from below. I would like "Washington Capitals" to be set as this.state.teamRank["0"]..."New York Islander" to be set as this.state.teamRank["1"] etc....

```
    this.state = {
      teamRank: {
        0: "",
        1: "",
        2: "",
        3: "",
        4: "",
        5: "",
        6: "",
        7: "",
      }
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url2 = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/standings';
    const response2 = await fetch(url2);
    const data2 = await response2.json();
    data2.records.map((element) => {
      element.teamRecords.map((element2, index) => {
        const teamNames = element2.team.name;
        const rankAndTeam = teamNames + index;
        console.log(rankAndTeam);
      });
    }
```

prints

```sh
Main.js:80Washington Capitals0
Main.js:80 New York Islanders1
Main.js:80 Pittsburgh Penguins2
Main.js:80 Carolina Hurricanes3
Main.js:80 Columbus Blue Jackets4
Main.js:80 Philadelphia Flyers5
Main.js:80 New York Rangers6
Main.js:80 New Jersey Devils7
```

REACT COMPONENT:

```
Want to put this.state.teamRank.['0'] where Name0 is...
Want to put this.state.teamRank.['1'] where Name1 is etc...
```

```html
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Username</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Name0</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Name1</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>@fat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Name2</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>@fat</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data2.records` array contains 4 objects. In each object your have `teamRecords` array, which self contains 8 objects.

Considering you want to show first 8 records only. You have two options.

Instead of object, you need to have array in state,

```
this.state = {
    teamRank: []
}
```

**Option 1**

Create an array, push each name in that array, and finally store that array in state.

```
let teamRank = [];
data2.records.map((element,ind)=>{
  element.teamRecords.map((element2,index) => {
    const teamNames = element2.team.name;
    const rankAndTeam = teamNames + index;
    console.log(rankAndTeam);
    teamRank.push(teamNames)
  });
})

this.setState({teamRank}, ()=>console.log(this.state.teamRank))
```

And you can print names like this,

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>{ this.state.teamRank && this.state.teamRank[0]}</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>{ this.state.teamRank && this.state.teamRank[1]}</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>@fat</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>{ this.state.teamRank && this.state.teamRank[2]}</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>@fat</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-obusab)

---

**Option 2**

You can create an array of array's by iterating over `data2.records`

```
let teamRank = data2.records.map((element,ind)=>{
  return element.teamRecords.map((element2,index) => {  //Notice the return
    const teamNames = element2.team.name;
    const rankAndTeam = teamNames + index;
    console.log(rankAndTeam);
    return teamNames;  //Notice the return
  }); 
})

this.setState({teamRank}, ()=>console.log(this.state.teamRank))
```

And you can print names like,

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>{ this.state.teamRank[0] && this.state.teamRank[0][0]}</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>{ this.state.teamRank[0] && this.state.teamRank[0][1]}</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>@fat</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>{ this.state.teamRank[0] && this.state.teamRank[0][2]}</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>@fat</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k1efud)

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a new object that will be your new state and then you set the state to this new object like this
(Since you are not creating a new array you can use forEach instead of map)

```
let newState = {}
element.teamRecords.forEach((element2,index) => {
          const teamNames = element2.team.name;
          const rankAndTeam = teamNames + index;
          console.log(rankAndTeam);
          // this will add a key of index (0,1,2,3...) with the team name as value 
          newState[index] = teamNames
   });
this.setState({ teamRank: newState})
```

in your component you can loop through the keys of your object and render the info

here you are creating an array of tr's React will handle this and render it properly

```
  // rank will be (0,1,2,3...)
 {Object.keys(this.state.teamRank).map(rank => (
    <tr>
       <td>{rank + 1}</td>
       <td>{this.state.teamRank[rank]}</td>
       <td>Otto</td>
       <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
```

Answer (score -2):

The second part of your question is simple JSX:

```
                               <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>{this.state.teamRank[0]}</td>
                                    <td>Otto</td>
                                    <td>@mdo</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>{this.state.teamRank[1]}</td>
                                    <td>Thornton</td>
                                    <td>@fat</td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>{this.state.teamRank[2]}</td>
                                    <td>Thornton</td>
                                    <td>@fat</td>
                                </tr>
```

EDIT: Try this alongside the top JSX:

```
     this.state = {
        teamRank:[
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ]
    }
}
async componentDidMount() {
const url2 = ('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/standings');
    const response2 = await (fetch(url2));
    const data2 = await response2.json();
    data2.records.map((element)=>{
            element.teamRecords.map((element2,index) => {
                const teamNames = element2.team.name;
                teamRank = this.state.teamRank
                teamRank[index] = name
                this.setState(teamRank: teamRank);
                const rankAndTeam = teamNames + index;
                console.log(rankAndTeam);
   });
}
```

Comment: Incorrect. this.state.teamRank[1] logs in undefined object